# $|G|$ and $|{\rm Aut}(G)|$ are relatively prime $\Rightarrow$ $G$ should be cyclic?

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

If $|G|$ and $|{\rm Aut}(G)|$ are relatively prime, then first, it can be shown that $G$ must be abelian: this is clear, since if $G$ would non-abelian then a prime divisor of $|G/Z(G)|$ (which divides $|G|$) is necessarily a divisor of $|{\rm Aut}(G)|$.

Therefore, we assume that $G$ is abelian group with $(|G|, |{\rm Aut}(G)|)=1$. It may be possible to deduce something more; I guess that $G$ must be cyclic. Is this true?

Comment: I'd phase the first point thus: $[G:Z(G)]=|\text{Inn}(G)|$ and so $[G:Z(G)]$ is a divisor of both $|G|$ and $|\text{Aut}(G)|$, which implies $[G:Z(G)]=1$ and $G=Z(G)$.

Comment: yes; I was trying to write in less number of words.

Comment: You could reduce the number of words by replacing "should be" by "is".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Consider the fundamental theorem of finitely generated abelian groups, plus the fact that every abelian group has $p$-primary components.

If $G$ has a copy of $C_{p^2}$, then ${\rm Aut}(G)$ has a copy of ${\rm Aut}(C_{p^2})$ whose size is divisible by $p$, and if $G$'s decomposition has a copy of $C_p\times C_p$ then ${\rm Aut}(G)$ has a copy of ${\rm Aut}(C_p\times C_p)$, again this is divisible by $p$. Therefore $G$ is cyclic of squarefree order.